# Set variable looses data outside of for loop

Tags: python, set, jinja2

For my solution using jinja template, I want to loop through a dictionary inside a list and filter out only the required data to be used in another for loop.

Initially I used set variable but the data got lost once outside the for loop. On reading more about it, I found a way to use namespace to be able to persist the state of the variable outside the for loop. Please see below code.

```
{% for question in questions %}
    <div class="question-box">
        <div class="question-parent">
            <div class="question-text">
                <h3 id="{{ question.question_id }}">{{ question.question_text }}</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="question-answer-box" name="{{ question.question_id }}">
            {% set ns = namespace(temp = "") %}
            {% for item in data %}  
                {% if item["question_instance_id"] == question.question_id %}
                    {% set ns.temp = item %}  
                    <p>{{ ns.temp }}</p>
                {% else %}
                    {% set ns.temp = "" %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %} 
            <p>{{ ns.temp }}</p>
            {% for choice in question.choices %}
            <p>{{ ns.temp }}</p>
            {% if choice.choice_id == ns.temp["response_answer"] %}
                <label><input type="radio" value="{{ choice.choice_id }}" name="{{ question.question_id }}" checked />
                {{ choice.choice_text }}
                </label>
                <br/> 
            {% else %} 
                <label><input type="radio" value="{{ choice.choice_id }}" name="{{ question.question_id }}" />
                {{ choice.choice_text }}
                </label>
                <br/> 
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
{% endfor %}
```

The first for loop is looping through all questions and displaying it on UI. The 2nd for loop is using a dictionary inside a list and comparing with the question.question_id, once a match is found that data needs to be passed to the next for loop inside the choice.

Problem is I still don't see ns.temp data when trying to print inside the choice for loop. Looks like it still didn't work and I have no clue what to try next.

Hence reaching out to the community and see if there is any other option?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should not clear the ns.temp if the comparison fails, it will clear an earlier found item.

Remove

```
                    {% else %}
                    {% set ns.temp = "" %}
```

Good Luck